# Перенос текста в checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

Можно ли сделать перенос длинного текста в checkbox?

Comment: А текст с использованием тега переноса пробовали ставить в чекбокс?
Т.е. так: `Текст, текст, текст \n текст текст текст`

Comment: распознает как \n